# Android How to change Total number of days into years,months and days exactly?

Tags: android, calendar, date-format

i am doing an app that is related to get the age of a person according to the given input of birthday date. for that i am getting the total number of days from that date to the current date from the below code.

```
      String strThatDay = "1991/05/10";
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
      Date d = null;
      try {

      try {
      d = formatter.parse(strThatDay);
      Log.i(TAG, "" +d);
      } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
      }
      } catch (ParseException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
      } 
      Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
      thatDay.setTime(d); //rest is the same....

      Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
      long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis(); 
      long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

from this code i am getting total number of days. so my requirement is convert the total number of days in to years ,months and days exactly.. please help....

Comment: There are mathematical operators called % and /, used for modulus and division respectively. 12 months in a year, 30 days in a month, 356 days in a year. That should be enough.

Comment: @VinaySShenoy how to do that one any simple example...

Comment: @VinaySShenoy for some years we have 355 days and for months 31,30,29 and 28 days. how can we resolve this problem

Comment: have a look at the similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976989/get-accurate-days-between-two-dates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/Duration.html) class :

```
Duration duration = new Duration();
duration.add( today );
duration.substract( birthDate);
int years = duration.getYears();
int months = duration.getMonths();
int days = duration.getDays();
```

Some other alternatives include using a library dedicated to time management : Joda time. See [Calculate age in Years, Months, Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710206/calculate-age-in-years-months-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

```
  String strThatDay = "1991/05/10";
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
  Date thatDate = null;
  try {

  try {
  thatDate = formatter.parse(strThatDay);

  Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
  thatDay.setTime(thatDate);
  Calendar toDay = Calendar.getInstance();
  toDay.setTime(thatDate);

  toDay.add(Calendar.DATE, noOfDays);

  int year = toDay.getTime().getYear() - thatDay.getTime().getYear();
  int month  = toDay.getTime().getMonth() - thatDay.getTime().getMonth();
    if(month<0){
       year--
       month = month+12;
     }
  int days  = toDay.getTime().getDate() - thatDay.getTime().getDate();
     if(month<0){
       month--
       days = days+ toDay.getMaximum(Calendar.MONTH);;
     }
```