# Calculate Difference between two times in Android

Tags: java, android, date, time

I have two string variables such as StartTime and EndTime. I need to Calculate the TotalTime by subtracting the EndTime with StartTime.

The Format of StartTime and EndTime is as like follows:

```
StartTime = "08:00 AM";
EndTime = "04:00 PM";
```

TotalTime in Hours and Mins Format. How to calculate this in Android?

Comment: The duration class is useful for this in Android : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12739537/693752

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try below code.

// suppose time format is into **("hh:mm a")**  format

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("08:00 AM");
date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("04:00 PM");

long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 
days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));  
hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60)); 
min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);
hours = (hours < 0 ? -hours : hours);
Log.i("======= Hours"," :: "+hours);
```

**Output** - Hours :: 8

Comment: Hey thank u , the difference is always negative, my start time was 12:30 PM and end time was 1:00 PM.  i have given it the format as "HH:mm a" and the difference is still negative. Althogh end time is greater than the start time.

Comment: Do I need to give the date with string as well?

Comment: use 01:00 PM instead of 1:00 PM and try what happend .

Comment: i have tried both but the hours difference is negavtive , even if I try 08:00 AM and 04:00 PM it returns minutes and hours as 0.0.I am doingit like this
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
  Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("08:00 AM");
  Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("04:00 PM");

  long difference = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();

  int days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));  
  int hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60)); 
  int min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);

Comment: @Munazza Here i post code after try by my self and i get result that i also log here.

Comment: @Chiragh , the type of date1 and date2 is Date ?

Comment: @Munazza Yes, it must be date.

Comment: date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("08:00 AM");
date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("04:00 PM"); When i debug After this point the date1 and date2 's milliseconds are -180000000 , thats so strange that u are getting correct output with the same code :(

Comment: I get value of difference is 0 @Chirag

Comment: This is very old code, so i need to check this code and if anything wrong then i will update the code

Comment: even i am getting the difference as 0 when i try your snippet.

Comment: No need to roll-your-own solution like this. The modern *java.time* classes can handle this work and do the math. See [this other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56413601/642706).

Comment: how to get seconds? What is the formula?

Answer (score 7):

Note: Corrected code as below which provide by Chirag Raval because in code which Chirag provided had some issues when we try to find time from 22:00 to 07:00.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("22:00");
Date endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("07:00");

long difference = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime(); 
if(difference<0)
{
    Date dateMax = simpleDateFormat.parse("24:00");
    Date dateMin = simpleDateFormat.parse("00:00");
    difference=(dateMax.getTime() -startDate.getTime() )+(endDate.getTime()-dateMin.getTime());
}
int days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));  
int hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60)); 
int min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);
Log.i("log_tag","Hours: "+hours+", Mins: "+min);
```

Result will be: Hours: 9, Mins: 0

Comment: Hi,  how to get seconds in the same format like above (mins, hours)?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), you can use it to parse your strings with the parse(String source) method and the you can easily manipulate the two Dates object to obtain what you want.

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstance();
Date date1 = df.parse(string1);
Date date2 = df.parse(string2);
long difference = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();

days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));  
hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60)); 
min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);

String diffHours = df.format(hours);
```

For date difference

```
Date myDate = new Date(difference);
```

The to show the Date :

```
String diff = df.format(myDate);
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, how to get seconds in the same format like above (mins, hours)?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this....

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    try {
        date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("08:00 AM");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("04:00 PM");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    int days = (int) (difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    int hours = (int) ((difference - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    int min = (int) (difference - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days) - (1000 * 60 * 60 * hours))
            / (1000 * 60);
    hours = (hours < 0 ? -hours : hours);
    Log.i("======= Hours", " :: " + hours);
```

Comment: Hi,  how to get seconds in the same format like above (mins, hours)?

Answer (score 2):

I should like to contribute the modern answer.

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String startTime = "08:00 AM";
    String endTime = "04:00 PM";

    LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(startTime, timeFormatter);
    LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(endTime, timeFormatter);

    Duration diff = Duration.between(start, end);

    long hours = diff.toHours();
    long minutes = diff.minusHours(hours).toMinutes();
    String totalTimeString = String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes);
    System.out.println("TotalTime in Hours and Mins Format is " + totalTimeString);
```

The output from this snippet is:

> TotalTime in Hours and Mins Format is 08:00

(Tested on Java 1.7.0_67 with ThreeTen Backport.)

The datetime classes used in the other answers — `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `DateFormat` and `Calendar` — are all long outdated and poorly designed. Possibly worse, one answer is parsing and calculating “by hand”, without aid from any library classes. That is complicated and error-prone and never recommended. Instead I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages: `org.threeten.bp.Duration`, `org.threeten.bp.LocalTime` and `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
String mStrDifferenceTime =compareTwoTimeAMPM("11:06 PM","05:07 AM");
Log.e("App---Time ", mStrDifferenceTime+" Minutes");

public static String getCurrentDateUsingCalendar() {
    Date mDate = new Date();  // to get the date
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // getting date in this format
    return mSimpleDateFormat.format(mDate.getTime());
}

public static String getNextDateUsingCalendar() {
    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    Date mStrTomorrow = mCalendar.getTime();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    return mDateFormat.format(mStrTomorrow);

}

public static String compareTwoTimeAMPM(String mStrStartTime, String mStrEndTime) {
    String mStrCompareStartTime[] = mStrStartTime.split(" ");
    String mStrCompareEndTime[] = mStrEndTime.split(" ");
    int mIStartTime = Integer.parseInt(mStrCompareStartTime[0].replace(":", ""));
    int mIEndTime = Integer.parseInt(mStrCompareEndTime[0].replace(":", ""));
    String mStrToday = "";
    String mStrTomorrow = "";
    if (mIStartTime < mIEndTime && mStrCompareStartTime[1].equals("PM") && mStrCompareEndTime[1].equals("PM")) {
        mStrToday = getCurrentDateUsingCalendar();
        mStrTomorrow = getCurrentDateUsingCalendar();
    } else if (mIStartTime < mIEndTime && mStrCompareStartTime[1].equals("AM") && mStrCompareEndTime[1].equals("AM")) {
        mStrToday = getCurrentDateUsingCalendar();
        mStrTomorrow = getCurrentDateUsingCalendar();
    } else if (mIStartTime > mIEndTime && mStrCompareStartTime[1].equals("PM") && mStrCompareEndTime[1].equals("PM")) {
        String mStrTime12[] = mStrCompareStartTime[0].split(":");
        if (mStrTime12[0].equals("12")) {
            mStrToday = getNextDateUsingCalendar();
            mStrTomorrow = getNextDateUsingCalendar();
        } else {
            mStrToday = getCurrentDateUsingCalendar();
            mStrTomorrow = getNextDateUsingCalendar();
        }
    } else if (mIStartTime > mIEndTime && mStrCompareStartTime[1].equals("AM") && mStrCompareEndTime[1].equals("AM")) {
        String mStrTime12[] = mStrCompareStartTime[0].split(":");
        if (mStrTime12[0].equals("12")) {
            mStrToday = getNextDateUsingCalendar();
            mStrTomorrow = getNextDateUsingCalendar();
        } else {
            mStrToday = getCurrentDateUsingCalendar();
            mStrTomorrow = getNextDateUsingCalendar();
        }
    } else if (mStrCompareStartTime[1].equals("PM") && mStrCompareEndTime[1].equals("AM")) {
        mStrToday = getCurrentDateUsingCalendar();
        mStrTomorrow = getNextDateUsingCalendar();
    } else if (mStrCompareStartTime[1].equals("AM") && mStrCompareEndTime[1].equals("PM")) {
        mStrToday = getCurrentDateUsingCalendar();
        mStrTomorrow = getCurrentDateUsingCalendar();
    }
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm aa");
    String mStrDifference = "";
    try {
        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(mStrToday + " " + mStrStartTime);
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(mStrTomorrow + " " + mStrEndTime);
        mStrDifference = differenceDatesAndTime(date1, date2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mStrDifference;

}


public static String differenceDatesAndTime(Date mDateStart, Date mDateEnd) {

    long different = mDateEnd.getTime() - mDateStart.getTime();
    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

    long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
    different = different % daysInMilli;

    long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
    different = different % hoursInMilli;

    long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;

    long minutes = elapsedHours * 60 + elapsedMinutes;
    long result = elapsedDays * 24 * 60 + minutes;
    if (0 > result) {
        result = result + 720;  //result is minus then add 12*60 minutes
    }

    return result + "";
}
```

My output is E/App---Time: 361 Minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension function in Kotlin like this:

```
fun Long.toTimeAgo(): String {
    val time = this
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()

    // convert back to second
    val diff = (now - time) / 1000

    return diff.toString()
}
```

To get the result in social format, one can modify the code as:

```
fun Long.toTimeAgo(): String {
    val time = this
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()

    // convert back to second
    val diff = (now - time) / 1000

    return when {
        diff < MINUTE -> "Just now"
        diff < 2 * MINUTE -> "a minute ago"
        diff < 60 * MINUTE -> "${diff / MINUTE} minutes ago"
        diff < 2 * HOUR -> "an hour ago"
        diff < 24 * HOUR -> "${diff / HOUR} hours ago"
        diff < 2 * DAY -> "a day ago"
        diff < 30 * DAY -> "${diff / DAY} days ago"
        diff < 2 * MONTH -> "a month ago"
        diff < 12 * MONTH -> "${diff / MONTH} months ago"
        diff < 2 * YEAR -> "a year ago"
        else -> "${diff / YEAR} years ago"
    }
}
```

And now in the code to get the time difference from a date in string, one can use:

```
    val date = SimpleDateFormat('your date pattern').parse(dateString)
    val timeString = date.time.toTimeAgo()
```

Answer (score -4):

```
Try simple piece of code using For 24 hour time
StartTime = "10:00";
EndTime = "13:00";
here starthour=10 and end hour=13 
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(txtDate.getText().toString())||TextUtils.isEmpty(txtDate1.getText().toString())||TextUtils.isEmpty(txtTime.getText().toString())||TextUtils.isEmpty(txtTime1.getText().toString()))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Date/Time fields cannot be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        if (starthour > endhour) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Time Should Be Less Than End Time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (starthour == endhour) {
            if (startmin > endmin) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Time Should Be Less Than End Time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                tvalid = "True";
            }
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sucess"+(endhour-starthour)+(endmin-startmin),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tvalid = "True";
        }
    }
same for date also
```