# Java Compare two times with custom start end time in a day

Tags: java, time, date-format

I'm getting two times (in the format HH:mm aa) say 6:00 pm to 5:00 pm.I need some generic and shortest way to compare these two times.

For instance:-

Say I am comparing 4pm and 7pm, then I should be getting 4pm > 7pm, since my start time is 6pm and end time is 5pm

Please help.

Comment: Have you had a look at the javadoc of `Date`?

Comment: Yes I did see the util.Date which has before and after however that applies to start and end time in a specific day. i.e. 12.00 am to 11:59 am

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate Difference between two times in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110621/calculate-difference-between-two-times-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
         // Per the JavaDoc:
         // the value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; a value 
         // less than 0 if this 
         // Date is before the Date argument; and a value greater
         // than 0 if this Date is after 
         // the Date argument.

         if (startDate.compareTo(endDate) < 0)
         {
            // before
         }
         else if (startDate.compareTo(endDate) == 0)
         {
            // same
         }
         else if (startDate.compareTo(endDate) > 0)
         {
            // after
         }
         else if (startDate.compareTo(firstDate) > 0 && startDate.compareTo(secondDate) < 0)
         {
            // between
         }
```

Insert your conditions as appropriate.

Comment: What will be the answer if I compare 4pm and 7pm I guess I will be getting 4PM < 7PM, which is not desired

Comment: @user3115056: See my edit.. You have to cover your conditions as appropriate.

Comment: Where is the endDate in the last condition?

Comment: @user3115056: I didn't use it because in this case you have three date objects. The intial and the other Date objects you are trying to compare.

Comment: Not the exact answer but kind off got a proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Date` and `.Calendar` classes built into Java are notoriously troublesome. Instead use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

## Joda-Time

Joda-Time has built-in support for the Java [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). And Joda-Time offers its own comparison methods: `isBefore`, `isBeforeNow`, `isAfter`, `isAfterNow`, `isEqual`.

### Example Code

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime yesterday = now.minusDays( 1 );
boolean isYesterdayBeforeNow = yesterday.isBefore( now ); // TRUE.
```

## java.time

In the java.time package, a `ZonedDateTime` offers methods such as `isBefore` and `isAfter`.

Comment: +1 Note, Joda Time is not available for people using GWT and have to use the method I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Date](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) has [before](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) and [after](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) methods and can be [compared to each other](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29).

so you could do something like this:

```
if(todayDate.after(historyDate) && todayDate.before(futureDate)) {
    // In between
}
```

Comment: I said there are 2 times within 6:pm to 5pm...
Say I am comparing 4pm and 7pm, then I should be getting 4pm > 7pm,
since my start time is 6pm and end time is 5pm.

Comment: you can override `compareTo()` method and adjust the `return` type to suit your need (specify 4 is greater than 6)