# Need to get the time difference between the two dates in hh:mm format

Tags: java, date

I need to get the time difference between to different dates in HH:MM format.Suppose I had two dates like this

> 02/26/2014 09:00:00 and  02/26/2014 19:30:00

I need to get the difference in hh:mm like 09:30.

I googled and tried to find solution for this but they are giving the individual hours and minutes.

I am not allowed to use Third party libraries like Joda for this. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

> UPDATE

I tried the following code

```
public class DateDifferentExample {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String dateStart = "02/26/2014 09:00:00";
    String dateStop = "02/26/2014 19:05:00";

    //HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

        //in milliseconds
        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

        System.out.println("Time difference-->"+diff);

        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        int diffInDays = (int) (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());

        System.out.println("Difference--> "+diffInDays);
       String difft=diffHours+":"+diffMinutes;
        System.out.println("Duration Time:"+difft);

        /*System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
        System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
        System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
        System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");*/

        //System.out.println("Getting date diff from the other method--->"+calculateDays(d1, d2));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

/*public static long getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    return timeUnit.convert(diffInMillies,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}*/

public static long calculateDays(Date dateEarly, Date dateLater) {  
       return (dateLater.getTime() - dateEarly.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);  
    }
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172377/java-compare-two-times-with-custom-start-end-time-in-a-day/22172630#22172630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TimeDiff {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        // Setup
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        long second = 1000l;
        long minute = 60l * second;
        long hour = 60l * minute;

        // parsing input
        Date date1 = dateFormat.parse("02/26/2014 09:00:00");
        Date date2 = dateFormat.parse("02/26/2014 19:30:00");

        // calculation
        long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

        // printing output
        System.out.print(String.format("%02d", diff / hour));
        System.out.print(":");
        System.out.print(String.format("%02d", (diff % hour) / minute));
        System.out.print(":");
        System.out.print(String.format("%02d", (diff % minute) / second));
    }

}
```

Keep in mind, that dates are not as easy as you could expect. There are leap seconds and all kind of weird stuff.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date d1 = df.parse("02/26/2014 09:00:00");
    Date d2 = df.parse("02/26/2014 19:30:00");
    long d = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    long hh = d / (3600 * 1000);
    long mm = (d - hh * 3600 * 1000) / (60 * 1000);
    System.out.printf("%02d:%02d", hh, mm);
```

prints

```
10:30
```

Comment: Instead of the manual conversion, you could use `long hh = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(d);` and `long mm = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(d) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hh);` to avoid careless mistakes.

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev I tried this earlier.But in case if the minutes is 5 .It will show like this 10:5.But I need to show in 10:05 like this

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse the timestamps into a `Date` using `SimpleDateFormat`.
2. Calculate the difference between `dateOne.getTime()` and `dateTwo.getTime()`.  The result will be the difference in milliseconds.
3. Use the `TimeUnit` instances to convert the milliseconds to hours and minutes.

Comment: @Ganesh No.  Please try to solve this problem by yourself according to the hints I gave you.  If there are specific problems, we can help you.  But we're not here to do your homework.

Comment: I already tried using TimeUnit.But I am not getting the desired output.Please look at my code in question that I updated.