# How do check time within specified Range or not?

Tags: java

I am allowing user to select a time for that i am using TimePicker in my Activity, and getting result in this format: `03:51 PM`

Now i have a **time range** like - `07:00 PM to 10:00 PM`

If selected time by user matches to time defined in time range, then need to show message **"Could be Dangerous"**

So finally i would like to know that How can i check that selected time within time range or not ?

I have already gone through to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110621/calculate-difference-between-two-times-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use jodatime for this. It's a very powerful lib.
[joda](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/)

Then you can implement like below

```
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse("07:00 PM", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("KK:mm a"));
    LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse("10:00 PM", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("KK:mm a"));

    LocalTime selected = new LocalTime(hourOfDay, minute);
    if (selected.isAfter(startTime) && selected.isBefore(endTime)) {
      // do your work
    }
```

Comment: please have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429438/joda-localtime-meridiem-parse

Answer (score 1):

you achieve it using following code...

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener lisTime = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override 
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
               if((hourOfDay >= 19 && hourOfDay < 22)  || (hourOfDay == 22 && minute == 0))
               {

                    // you can code here time is between 7PM to 10PM
               }
               else
               {
                    // continition not satiesfied
               }


            } 
        };
```

Comment: an easy way ... i ticked as useful

Answer (score 0):

Convert the two strings to Date objects (which are also time objects) then Create a new Date object.

This will contain the current time.
Use the `Date.before()` and `Date.after()` methods to determine if you are in the time interval.

```
public static final String inputFormat = "HH:mm";

private Date date;
private Date dateCompareOne;
private Date dateCompareTwo;

private String compareStringOne = "9:45";
private String compareStringTwo = "1:45";

SimpleDateFormat inputParser = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, Locale.US);

private void compareDates(){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    date = parseDate(hour + ":" + minute);
    dateCompareOne = parseDate(compareStringOne);
    dateCompareTwo = parseDate(compareStringTwo);

    if ( dateCompareOne.before( date ) && dateCompareTwo.after(date)) {
        //yada yada
    }
}

private Date parseDate(String date) {

    try {
        return inputParser.parse(date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        return new Date(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i use it in my existing code, as you know l already accepted time by user

Comment: see carefully the code is changing the time string to a date object according to the input format