# Joda LocalTime Meridiem parse

Tags: java, android, jodatime

When I use `08:00 AM` as `startTime` and `09:00 AM` as `endTime` then my `if` statement works perfect

```
LocalTime selected = new LocalTime(hourOfDay, minute);
if (selected.isAfter(startTime) && selected.isBefore(endTime)) {
    // doing some work
}
```

But whenever i use `11:00 PM` as `startTime` and `02:00 AM` as `endTime` then my if statement not working.

```
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse("11:00 PM", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("KK:mm a"));
LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse("02:00 AM", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("KK:mm a"));

LocalTime selected = new LocalTime(hourOfDay, minute);
if (selected.isAfter(startTime) && selected.isBefore(endTime)) {
    // doing some work
}
```

Comment: What is the selected time?

Comment: I guess its not in (11 pm ... 00 am ... 1 am .... 2am) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `startTime` as bigger than your `endTime` in the 2nd example. There can be no time that is bigger than 11:00 PM and smaller than 2:00 AM.

Edit:

You must check if startTime is bigger than endTime and change your query accordingly, f.e.:

```
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse("11:00 PM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("KK:mm a"));
LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse("02:00 AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("KK:mm a"));

LocalTime selected = LocalTime.parse("01:00 AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("KK:mm a"));

if (startTime.isBefore(endTime)) {
    if (selected.isAfter(startTime) && selected.isBefore(endTime)) {
        System.out.println("It works!");
    }
} else if (startTime.isAfter(endTime)) {
    if (selected.isAfter(startTime) || selected.isBefore(endTime)) {
        System.out.println("It works!");
    }
} else {
    // Decide what to do if startTime and endTime are equal.
}
```

Comment: I have updated the example above. What is your output? (Note: I tested it with the Java 8 classes, so you probably need to change the formatter parts)

Comment: i tried again check my updated code and let me know where i am missing ?'

Comment: thank you so much, tricky issue but easiest solution, i have accepted your answer and tapped as useful too