# how to find difference between two date Time string?

Tags: android, datetime

I am calculating time difference between two dates and time but its restuning invalid difference.

here's my sample date and code to calculate the difference.

```
loginTime=2016-01-24 12:04:30.16
expiryTime = 2016-01-24 13:04:30.16

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date now = new Date();


        try {
            Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(loginTime);
            Date expireDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(expiryTime);

//            String temCurrentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(now);
//            Date currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(temCurrentDate);
//            String day_of_week = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(now);

            long difference =startDate.getTime()- expireDate.getTime();

            int hour = (int) difference / (60 * 60 * 1000);


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Difference between this time is 1 hour but i am getting 11 or 13. Please tell where i am going wrong in this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate Difference between two times in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110621/calculate-difference-between-two-times-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Spelling error in your variable:

```
simpleDateFormat.parse(expiryTime);
```

Does not match:  `ExpiryTime = 2016-01-24 13:04:30.16`

That's the whole problem.

Comment: i made this spelling mistake while typing question

Comment: Well, curiously, that error would cause your code to find a difference of many hours since one of the times is blank.