# To calculate difference between two times in android studio

Tags: java, android

1. I created buttons for display current time for start and stop parking and its work.
2. But when I clicked on the deductbtn, the apps on the phone will pop up and show "my Application 1 has stopped"
3. How can I fix this? Any help will be much appciated.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_info);

   firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   parkBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.parkBtn);
   stopparkBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopparkBtn);
   deductBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deductBtn);
   timeResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeResult);
   timeResult2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeResult2);
   diffResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.diffResult);


   parkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           final Date d = new Date();
           SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
           final String currentDateTimeString = sdf1.format(d);
           timeResult.setText(currentDateTimeString);

       }
   });

   stopparkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           final Date d1= new Date();
           SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
           final String currentDateTimeString1 = sdf2.format(d1);
           timeResult2.setText(currentDateTimeString1);


       }
   });

   deductBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

           float totalTime = Float.parseFloat(timeResult2.getText().toString());
           float totalTime1 = Float.parseFloat(timeResult.getText().toString());
           final float timeUsage = totalTime - totalTime1;
           diffResult.setText(String.valueOf(timeUsage));

       }
   });

   }

   }
   ```

Comment: Provide the Logcat errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate Difference between two times in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110621/calculate-difference-between-two-times-in-android)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the code first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @NorSakinah kalau ada soalan lagi tanya lah,

Answer (score 1):

The new code is here :
         @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

```
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
            Date date1 = null;
            try {
                date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(timeResult.getText().toString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Date date2 = null;
            try {
                date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(timeResult2.getText().toString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String diffResult= DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date1.getTime(), date2.getTime(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME).toString();
            deductBtn.setText(diffResult);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception because

```
float totalTime = Float.parseFloat(timeResult2.getText().toString());
float totalTime1 = Float.parseFloat(timeResult.getText().toString());
```

Here, If you click this button after performing click on other buttons, then textview's text will be in the **`format hh:mm a`**

And if you click button for the first time without clicking other buttons , The **`strings will be empty`**

Both will throw exception

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float

You can use,

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(timeResult2.getText().toString());
date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(timeResult.getText().toString());
String diff= DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date1.getTime(), date2.getTime(), DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS).toString();
```

Make sure that your textviews strings are not empty before doing it.

Comment: I see, since the timeResult is in TextView, I can't just simply substract like this: timeResult2 - timeResult. How can I fix this?

Comment: check #Nilesh Rathod comment. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110621/calculate-difference-between-two-times-in-android) has what you want . And I will edit it in my answer

Comment: I used the code that you give and I added try & catch and it works! thank  you ^-^