# How to Calculate Time Difference Between Two TIMESTAMP in Android

Tags: android, time

I am saving Current Date time as Timestamp with below code in my Android

```
 userValues.put("rTime",  ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

Now I want to calculate difference as

`String posttime=1576917051506 //retrieve saved timestamp 
 String currenttime=ServerValue.TIMESTAMP //current time
 difference=1hour 25 minutes`

how can i achieve this

Comment: This has bern asked and answered before. What did your search turn up?

Comment: apologize i did not find any regarding timestamp in android

Comment: I worte [this modern answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56413601/5772882) for Android. You may also use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23176621/5772882). To use it on Android if your API level happens to be 25 or lower, you need to add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project, though. If any pieces are still missing, I believe your search engine can supply them.

Comment: The answers posted so far are hand calculating the hours and the minutes. I recommend that instead you leave that calculation to library methods to the greatest extend possible. The `Duration` class from java.time and/or ThreeTenABP will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String posttime=1576917051506  
 String currenttime=ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

**first of all convert times to Long**

```
   long time1 = Long.valueof(posttime)
   long time2 = Long.valueof(currenttime)
   long diffrence  = time2-time1
   String myValue = convertSecondsToHMmSs(diffrence)
```

Now **myValue** is your time diffrence. like 1h:2m

```
  public static String convertSecondsToHMmSs(long millis) {
       long seconds = (millis / 1000) % 60;
long minutes = (millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
long hours = millis / (1000 * 60 * 60);

StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
b.append(hours == 0 ? "00" : hours < 10 ? String.valueOf("0" + hours) : 
String.valueOf(hours));
b.append(":");
b.append(minutes == 0 ? "00" : minutes < 10 ? String.valueOf("0" + minutes) :     
String.valueOf(minutes));
b.append(":");
b.append(seconds == 0 ? "00" : seconds < 10 ? String.valueOf("0" + seconds) : 
String.valueOf(seconds));
return b.toString();
    }
```

Comment: this return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", h,m,s); giving error can not return value from a method with void result type

Comment: please check @Mithu

Comment: Note* Do not use any external lib.

Comment: public String convertSecondsToHMmSs(long millis) {} . please check this carefully.  (Did your function retrun type String or void?)

Answer (score 1):

**Using Joda time:**

```
DateTime startTime, endTime;
Period p = new Period(startTime, endTime);
long hours = p.getHours();
long minutes = p.getMinutes();
```

Comment: Using Joda-Time may be a good suggestion in this case. That project is in maintenance mode, but it may be offering the best you can have on Android.