# Java method to find difference between 2 date objects in years, months and days

Tags: java

I have a start date and end date. the duration between the 2 dates should be in the form of years, months and days. I am new to java. 
When I run the below method the out I get is 0 years, 12 months 1 days.
Please suggest an alternative to get accurate difference in years, months and days.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Duration {

    private String getAssignmentDuration(java.util.Date oldDate, java.util.Date newDate) {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (oldDate.compareTo(newDate) > 0) {
            c1.setTime(newDate);
            c2.setTime(oldDate);
        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid");
            return "Invalid selection";

        }
        int year = 0;
        int month = 0;
        int days = 0;
        boolean doneMonth = false;
        boolean doneYears = false;
        while (c1.before(c2)) {
            //log.debug("Still in Loop");
            if (!doneYears) {
                c1.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                year++;
            }
            if (c1.after(c2) || doneYears) {
                if (!doneYears) {
                    doneYears = true;
                    year--;
                    c1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
                }   
                if (!doneMonth) {
                    c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                    month++;
                }
                if (c1.after(c2) || doneMonth) {
                    if (!doneMonth) {
                        doneMonth = true;
                        month--;
                        c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                    }

                    c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                    days++;
                    if (c1.after(c2)) {
                        days--;
                    }
                    // this will not be executed
                    if (days == 31 || month==12) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(year + " years, " + month + " months, " + days + " days");
        return year + " years, " + month + " months, " + days + " days";

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duration d1= new Duration();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        java.util.Date oldDate = null;
        try {
            oldDate = sdf.parse("2012/08/29");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.util.Date newDate = null;
        try {
            newDate = sdf.parse("2013/08/31");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        d1.getAssignmentDuration(oldDate, newDate);
    }

}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: it is possible duplicate of below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491679/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-dates-using-java

Comment: @Fuzzyfelt he already posted the code segment that he tried. then what is the purpose of your question ?

Comment: @sunil in my opinion the OP has made no effort to debug the code and is looking for someone to give them the solution

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 15):

```
 public static String getDateDifferenceInDDMMYYYY(Date from, Date to) {
        Calendar fromDate=Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar toDate=Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDate.setTime(from);
        toDate.setTime(to);
        int increment = 0;
        int year,month,day;
        System.out.println(fromDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        if (fromDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > toDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
            increment =fromDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }
         System.out.println("increment"+increment);
// DAY CALCULATION
        if (increment != 0) {
            day = (toDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + increment) - fromDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            increment = 1;
        } else {
            day = toDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - fromDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }

// MONTH CALCULATION
        if ((fromDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + increment) > toDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            month = (toDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 12) - (fromDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + increment);
            increment = 1;
        } else {
            month = (toDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)) - (fromDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + increment);
            increment = 0;
        }

// YEAR CALCULATION
        year = toDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) - (fromDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) + increment);
     return   year+"\tYears\t\t"+month+"\tMonths\t\t"+day+"\tDays";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(1999,01,8);
       /*  Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.set(2012,01,23);*/
        System.out.println(getDateDifferenceInDDMMYYYY(calendar.getTime(),new Date()));
    }
```

Comment: Adding an explanation would be nice.

Comment: Nice answer. It gives the difference in years, months and days, accounting for when the days wrap over a month boundary, or the months wrap over a year boundary.

Useful if you want to say 'X expires in 1 year, 2 months and 19 days'

Comment: Thanks this saved my time. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

Joda Time has a concept of time [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_interval.html) that you can use, like:

```
Interval interval = new Interval(oldDate.getTime(), newDate.getTime());
```

Then using a [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html) object, like:

```
Period period = interval.toPeriod().normalizedStandard(PeriodType.yearMonthDay());

PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .appendYears()
            .appendSuffix(" year ", " years ")
            .appendSeparator(" and ")
            .appendMonths()
            .appendSuffix(" month ", " months ")
            .appendSeparator(" and ")
            .appendDays()
            .appendSuffix(" day ", " days ")
            .toFormatter();
System.out.println(formatter.print(period));
```

You will easily be able to print your diference in years and months.

Probably you changes something while posting the question, because to fix your code (note that I didn't tested if your code will work with all sort of ranges), you only need to properly initialize the Calendar objects and the reverse the invalid selection check:

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
if (oldDate.compareTo(newDate) < 0) {
    c2.setTime(newDate);
    c1.setTime(oldDate);
} else {
    System.out.println("invalid");
    return "Invalid selection";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to obtain the duration without using joda or milli seconds approach? Milliseconds might not provide accurate duration in some locales. Hence i dont wanna use it. Could you please provide a modification in the code that i have used to provide accurate duration.

Comment: @user1776304 If you need to perform the transformation in a specified locale settings, you can use: `Interval(long startInstant, long endInstant, DateTimeZone zone)`. I suggest you should use the joda approach, to fix your code see my updated answer.

Comment: Even with the fix the output is o years, 12 months, 1 days.. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: @Vidya probably, you are running a different code then what is posted, since I just tested and it's printing: 1 years, 0 months, 2 days

Comment: Yes sorry am debugging a different code where in the oldDate  is 2012/08/31 and newDate is 2013/08/29. The duration is shown wrong. There is variation in days.

Comment: @Vidya The issue is because you are comparing at first at the year level. Since in this new case the difference is less then an year, but the years are different you count the year difference.

Comment: ok thanks.So Is there a different way to compute it other than using joda?

Comment: @Vidya sure there are, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4710304, but in the end if you would like to be accurate, you will have to implement what Joda time implemented.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
Period.between( 
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , 
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 27 ) 
)
```

Call:

```
.getYears()
.getMonths()
.getDays()
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are use troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by java.time classes.

## Using java.time

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

> today.toString(): 2017-05-05

For our example, we create another `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate earlier = today.minusMonths( 2 ).minusWeeks( 3 ).minusDays( 2 ) ;
```

> earlier.toString(): 2017-02-10

To represent a span of time unattached to the timeline in the granularity of years-month-days, use the [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class.

```
Period p = Period.between( earlier , today ) ;
int years = p.getYears();
int months = p.getMonths();
int days = p.getDays();
```

See [this code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/MPQyOS).

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines formats for textual representations of date-time values. For durations of years-months-days, the pattern is [`PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) where `P` marks the beginning and `T` separates the years-months-days portion from the hours-minutes-seconds portion.

The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. The `Period` class generates this particular pattern in its `toString` method.

```
String output = p.toString() ;
```

> p.toString(): P2M25D

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have `Date date1, date2` and they are initialized where `date1>date2`.

```
long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime(); //this is going to give you the difference in milliseconds

Date result = new Date(diff);
Format frmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yy MM dd HH:mm:ss");
return frmt.format(result).toString();//or if you want system.out.println(...);
```

Comment: I think on code line 3, you mean `new Date(diff)` and not `new Date(time)`... But your answer seems like the correct one... +1

Comment: Well, nice answer but the `getTime()` method returns the time in milliseconds and not in seconds.

Comment: i upvoted this, and used in my application, but had to subtract 1970 from the resulting years, since getTime() gives the Unix time, which is milliseconds since the start of 01/01/1970, if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 1):

```
    long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - birth.getTimeInMillis();


    // Calculate difference in seconds
    long Seconds = diff / 1000;

    // Calculate difference in minutes
    long Minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);

    // Calculate difference in hours
    long Hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);

    // Calculate difference in days
    long Days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    long Months = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 12 * 1000);

    //lblTsec, lblTmint, lblthours,lblTdays;
    System.out.println("Seconds : " + Seconds + "");
    System.out.println("Minutes : " + Minutes + "");
    System.out.println("Hours : " + Hours + "");
    System.out.println("Days : " + Days + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long[] differenceBetweenDates(Date fromDate, Date toDate) {
    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    startDate.setTime(fromDate);
    long years = 0;
    long months = 0;
    long days = 0;
    Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    endDate.setTime(toDate);
    Calendar tmpdate = Calendar.getInstance();
    tmpdate.setTime(startDate.getTime());

    tmpdate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    while (tmpdate.compareTo(endDate) <= 0) {
        startDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        tmpdate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        years++;
    }
    tmpdate.setTime(startDate.getTime());
    tmpdate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    while (tmpdate.compareTo(endDate) <= 0) {
        startDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        tmpdate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        months++;
    }
    tmpdate.setTime(startDate.getTime());
    tmpdate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    while (tmpdate.compareTo(endDate) <= 0) {
        startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        tmpdate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        days++;
    }
    return new long[]{days, months, years};
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the solution?

Comment: Function will give you the difference between the years. ie years +  months + days = difference

Comment: Function will give you the difference between the dates in sum of years, months and dates. ie years + months + days = difference

Answer (score 0):

Simply you could calculate difference between two dates milliseconds and divide by seconds, minutes, hours, days and month

suppose you want to get difference between years try this,

```
public int findDiff(Date fromDate, Date toDate) {

    if(fromDate == null || toDate == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    long diff = toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime();

    int diffInYears = (int) (diff / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24 * 30.41666666 * 12));
    return diffInYears;
}
```

suppose you want difference between months remove 12(means months) from the divider. likewise you can get days, hours, minutes..