# How to calculate No of Years, Months and days between two dates using Joda-Time

Tags: java, android, jodatime, android-jodatime

I'm using below code to  calculate  No  of Years, Months and days between two dates using `Joda-Time`

```
public void getDateDiff(View view) {

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").withLocale(Locale.US);
    DateTime startDate = null;
    DateTime endDate = null;

    // expected output 23...2....29

    try {
        startDate = formatter.parseDateTime("01/09/1995");
        endDate = formatter.parseDateTime("30/11/2018");

        Period period = new Period(startDate, endDate);

        Log.e("No Of Years : ", period.getYears() + " Years, ");
        Log.e("No Of Months : ", period.getMonths() + " Months, ");
        Log.e("No Of Days : ", period.getDays() + " Days, ");

        tvResult.setText(String.format("No Of Years : %d Years, \nNo Of Months : %d Months, \nNo Of Days : %d Days, ", period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

The expected output of above code is( [checked using this site](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=1&m1=9&y1=1995&d2=30&m2=11&y2=2018) and using one app in google play store)

```
23 years, 2 months, 29 days
```

but I'm getting below result using same date

```
/goku.com.demo E/No Of Years :: 23 Years, 
/goku.com.demo E/No Of Months :: 2 Months, 
/goku.com.demo E/No Of Days :: 1 Days,
```

Can any one help me to find issue what I'm missing in above code

> I'm using using below `joda-time` Dependency.

```
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
```

**P.S.** already checked below links

- [Getting the exact years or days or months between two joda date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795066/getting-the-exact-years-or-days-or-months-between-two-joda-date)
- [How to calculate difference between two dates in years...etc with Joda-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667884/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-dates-in-years-etc-with-joda-time)

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried supplying `PeriodType.yearMonthDay()` as third argument to the `Period` constructor?

Comment: @MCEmperor  No can u explain more about `PeriodType.yearMonthDay()` because i'm totally new in `joda-time`  and thanks for the response

Comment: And have you considered migrating to the new Java Date and Time API, from the `java.time` package?

Comment: @MCEmperor  if you any solution using `Java Date and Time API` feel free to past an answer

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque sir thank so much for this info using `Java 8 Date and Time API` in my android project its required `API level 26` while my min API level is 21 is there any other way i can use `Java Date and Time API` in API level 21

Comment: Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: FYI, *Joda-Time*, *java.time*, and *ThreeTen-Backport* are all led by the same man, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen). He designed the API of the backport to mimic as closely as possible the API of *java.time*. Later, if you ever want to migrate to the built-in classes and away from the back-port, you will need do little more than change your `import` statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that your Joda Time code does not work, is because if you don't provide a `PeriodType` object, then the standard PeriodType is used. The [standard](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/PeriodType.html#standard--) period type defines not only years, months and days to be included in the Period calculation, but also weeks. And you're not displaying the number of weeks, which is 4 in your case. If you write `period.getWeeks()` it'll return `4`.

In order to make it work, you have to provide a `PeriodType` as third argument to the `Period` constructor. If you change the declaration of `period` to

```
Period period = new Period(startDate, endDate, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
```

then it'll work. The period calculation will then only use the year, month and day fields.

## But

...it is better to migrate to the new Java Date and Time API available in the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package, if you are using Java 8 or above. Don't get me wrong, Joda Time is a very good date and time API. Java 8's date and time API is heavily influenced on Joda Time, because of its quality. Its lead developer is actually the same person, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

But Joda Time is now in maintenance mode, and on its website users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

#### Using Java 8 Date and Time API

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").withLocale(Locale.US);

// expected output 23...2....29
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("01/09/1995", f);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse("30/11/2018", f);
Period period = Period.between(startDate, endDate);
```

#### Backport to Java 6 and 7; Android support

Most of the `java.time` functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, also led by Stephen Colebourne. Further adapted for earlier Android API levels (below [26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_8.0_Oreo_(API_26))) in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [How to use ThreeTenABP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Note that there are [some differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24635657/507738) between Joda Time and the Java Date and Time API. In particular, the `Period` class from the Java Date and Time API is less comprehensive. However, the `Period` class from the Java Date and Time API provides the functionality which meets your requirement.

---

<sup>I see that this code using `java.time` is actually the same as @MaxXFrenzY's. This is not because of copy-paste, that is because the new Java Date and Time API is designed to be both unambiguous and straightforward.</sup>

Comment: Please use `yearMonthDay()` instead of `yearMonthDayTime()` which takes better into account the fact that the OP is not interested in the time part. And for the record: `java.time.Period` only works because by accident it supports exactly what the OP wants but else offers a very limited choice of period types (only one) compared with Joda-Time.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I've updated the code. I was looking for more information about Joda Time, and [then I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24635657/507738) – that's right, your own post. ;-) I'll include it in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

With [Java 8 time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API it would be easy to achieve the result using [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
....

    public void test() {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").withLocale(Locale.US);
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("01/09/1995", formatter);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse("30/11/2018", formatter);

        Period period = Period.between(startDate, endDate);
        System.out.println(String.format("No Of Years : %d Years, \nNo Of Months : %d Months, \nNo Of Days : %d Days, ",
                period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays())
        );
    }
```

The result printed is:

```
No Of Years : 23 Years, 
No Of Months : 2 Months, 
No Of Days : 29 Days,
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this without Joda-Time
There can be used wrong milliseconds for types but it will look like this

```
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
     Locale.getDefault());
     final Date startdate = format.parse("2018-10-20 23:34:32");
     final Date enddate = format.parse("2019-09-19 23:34:32");
     long n = enddate.getTime() - startdate.getTime();
                    if (n>0) {
                        long year, month, day, hour, minute, second;
                        // year = 365 days
                        year = (n/31536000000);
                        if (year != 0)
                            n = n - (year * 31536000000);
                        // month = 30 Days
                        month = (n/2592000000);
                        if (month != 0)
                            n = n - (month * 2592000000);
                        day = (n / 86400000);
                        if (day != 0)
                            n = n - (day * 86400000);
                        hour = (n / 3600000);
                        if (hour != 0)
                            n = n - (hour * 3600000);
                        minute = (n / 60000);
                        if (minute != 0)
                            n = n - (minute * 60000);
                        second = (n / 1000);
                     }
```