# How to find difference between two dates in years months and days in Java?

Tags: java, date-difference, date

Suppose I have :
**Employee** model which has ***startDate*** as its property variable and **Promotion** model has **promotionDate**. 
I want to find out for how long employee has  worked until his promotion for which I have to find difference between promotionDate and startDate.
If I get startDate as **employee.getStartDate()** and promotionDate as **promotion.getPromotionDate**, how can I find difference in years months and days for any dates,

Any help would be really appreciated.

**UPDATE : I SOLVED PROBLEM AS BELOW**

```
String startDate = "2018-01-01";
String promotionDate = "2019-11-08";

LocalDate sdate = LocalDate.parse(startDate);
LocalDate pdate = LocalDate.parse(promotionDate);

LocalDate ssdate = LocalDate.of(sdate.getYear(), sdate.getMonth(), sdate.getDayOfMonth());
LocalDate ppdate = LocalDate.of(pdate.getYear(), pdate.getMonth(), pdate.getDayOfMonth());

Period period = Period.between(ssdate, ppdate);
System.out.println("Difference: " + period.getYears() + " years " 
                                  + period.getMonths() + " months "
                                  + period.getDays() + " days ");
```

Thank you.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Is that March 4 or 3 April? How would it be 2 months and 2 days?? In any case you need like `Period.between(LocalDate.of(2015, Month.JANUARY, 1), LocalDate.of(2018, Month.APRIL, 3))`. The example yields a period of `P3Y3M2D`, read as a period of 3 years 3 months 2 days. [Link to documentation of the `Period` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Period.html).

Comment: I recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24048565/5772882) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43795903/5772882) (the two are similar in substance).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It‘s always a good idea to search, and search pretty thoroughly, before posting a question. Often you will find a good answer faster that way.

Comment: @NicholasK yes I have tried as per answer provided which solved my problem.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes you are right. Next time I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Using [`LocalDate.of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-) from java8 you can create two dates and find the difference:

```
LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 1);
LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 4);

Period period = Period.between(firstDate, secondDate);
```

[`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) has such methods as `.getYears()`, `.getMonths()` etc.

If you have `java.util.Date` objects instead of int values `2015, 1, 1`, you can convert `Date` to `LocalDate` before:

```
LocalDate startLocalDate = startDate.toInstant()
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDate();
```

Comment: Previously I asked question in generalized way but I have updated the question as per my real problem.  Here  in your answer: LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 1) . instead of providing 2015, 1, 1  as actual values  how can  I find the diiference?

Comment: @rizius updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update.  But if I have startDate as of type String , can I convert that into LocalDate ?