# how to get years, months and days from date of birth in java

Tags: java

I want to calculate years, months and days from dob.

Example: 2017-04-01

Answer: 0yrs 4 months  27 days.

Please help me how can i do it in java.

Comment: There is an additional step to convert `2017-04-01` to a bona-fide Java `Date` object, but a 5 second search will also reveal how to do that.

Comment: Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710206/calculate-age-in-years-months-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds

Comment: @Abhi thankyou very much